# Python PyTorrent library import error

Tags: python, attributeerror, sigkill

I am working with Python for a month now and I have still a lot of things to achieve. I was trying to code an easy torrent crawler for my favourite torrent source and download the file itself other than torrent. I succeeded with downloading .torrent file but I can not download the file with the .torrent file.

My research brought me to PyTorrent library. So I downloaded it using

```
pip install PyTorrent
```

However when I try to import it here is what I have :

[image: the error I get]

You can see my system and my python version from the screenshot above. And, I am running python on windows8, the screenshot is from PowerShell.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't post *images* of text.  Just copy and paste the text.  It makes it the question more searchable (so that someone else searching for the same error someday can find it).

Answer (score 1):

The `SIGKILL` symbol is generally part of the `signal` module in Python.  The documentation for `signal` includes the following statement:

> Note that not all systems define the same set of signal names; only those names defined by the system are defined by this module.

It looks like the `signal` module, when used on Windows, does not provide `SIGKILL`.  It's probable that *PyTorrent* was written on and generally used under Linux.  You could probably fix that particular error yourself, but it looks like this module hasn't been maintained in years (if you're using the same `PyTorrent` module I found in my googles).